# Is it permissible to use perfumes during menstruation?

Tags: halal-haram, women, menses

What is the ruling regarding the use of perfumes during menstruation? Is it permissible to use perfumes during it?

Comment: Why should it be forbidden?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of ahadith that restrict the usage of perfumes.  Relevant to women are notably:

> It was narrated that Al-Ash'ari said:  "The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: '**Any woman who puts on perfume then passes by people so that they can smell her fragrance then she is an adulteress.**'" -- Sunan an-Nasa'i 5126 [grade: hasan] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/nasai/48/87))
>
> It was narrated that Abu Hurairah said:
> "The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: '**If a woman has perfumed herself with incense, let her not attend 'Isha' prayer.**'" -- Sunan an-Nasa'i 5128 [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://www.sunnah.com/nasai/48/89))

There's also a difference of scholarly opinion concerning alcohol in perfumes, based on whether alcohol is impure [and not just forbidden as an intoxicant] (see [Islamic Centre](http://www.islamiccentre.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=274:perfumes-with-alcohol-permissible-in-islam&Itemid=88)).

Thus, I suspect the OP thinks that perfumes are generally either forbidden or discouraged based on the above, and thus is asking if it's still forbidden/discouraged during menstruation.  However, **the default stance with perfumes is permissibility**.

There are ways to misuse perfumes which are forbidden, e.g., with the intention of letting non-mahram men smell it (Islam Q&A fatwa [102329](https://islamqa.info/en/102329)), and when attending mosque (Islam Q&A fatwa [7850](https://islamqa.info/en/7850)).  These apply whether or not a woman is menstruating.

---

There's even the hadith:

> It was narrated from 'Aishah that:  Asma asked the Messenger of Allah about bathing after ones's period. He said: "... **Then she should take a piece of cotton perfumed with musk and purify herself with it.**" ... -- Sunan Ibn Majah [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1256410))

which has been interpreted as encouraging perfuming during menstruation:

> The reason for using this is to perfume the site and ward off unpleasant odours. -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/101779)